# Insertar datos en 2 tablas diferentes

Tags: php, sql

Buenas requiero insertar datos de un registro de un usuario en 2 ablas diferentes, el id en la tabla usuarios es la primary key y en la tabla propietarios es el FK pero al hacer el query no me los registra registra en la tabla usuarios pero no en la de los propietarios, espero puedan ayudarme en los '' que estan solos es porque en las tablas tengo el id autoincrementable

```js
<?php
session_start();
require_once('./../../conexion.php');
// recuperamos los datos del formulario
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$correo = ($_POST['correo']);
$clave =sha1(md5(123456));
$apartamento = $_POST['apartamento'];
$alicuota= $_POST['alicuota'];
$estado='Al dia';

// echo $nombre . "<br>";
// echo $apellido . "<br>";
// echo $correo . "<br>";
 // echo $clave . "<br>";
// echo $apartamento . "<br>";
// echo $alicuota ;


$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES('','$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$clave','$apartamento', '2',   
'$alicuota' )";

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);





$consulta2 = "INSERT INTO propietarios VALUES('','$nombre','$apellido','$apartamento','$estado' )";

$query2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);


if ($query2) {
 ?>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=./../index1.php"> 
 <?php
}
#header('Location: condominio.php');
?>
```

Comment: me conentaron que usara password hash pero debo usar que version de php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola! Si estás generando el ID del usuario con un auto_increment, entonces ese ID aún no existe en tu código cuando ejecutas el segundo insert, el de los propietarios.

Para poder crear el segundo registro, debes obtener el ID generado en la base de datos. Eso se logra ejecutando otra consulta SQL inmediatamente después del primer insert:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Con esta consulta, obtienes el ID, que luego podrás usar en el insert a la tabla propietarios. Asumo que en esta tabla, la cadena vacía hace referencia al ID del usuario, cierto? Si ese campo es la FK de usuario, debieras colocar allí el ID del usuario recién creado en la sentencia anterior. De hecho, por eso es que no te inserta nada en la tabla propietarios, ya que le envías una cadena vacía en donde debe ir el ID asociado a la FK, Mysql no sabe a quién asociar el nuevo registro, y por eso no hace nada. Igual aprovecha de capturar los errores de Mysql, para tener siempre los códigos de error a la mano cuando quieras hacer preguntas por acá o en google ^_~

Para más info, revisa el link de documentación oficial de Mysql, para la función LAST_INSERT_ID:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html

Y para conocer el uso de la clase mysqli que estás usando para conectarte desde php:
http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php

Comment: Gracias por eso quinqui

Comment: Mira, me acordé que PHP podría tener la funcionalidad ya implementada, y voilà! Sí la tiene ^_^ http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php